# Issue using If statement in Python

Tags: python

Input:

```
import random
I = 0
z = []
while I < 6:
    y = random. Choices(range(1,50))
    if y in z:
        break
    z += y
    I += 1
print(z)
```

Output:
[8, 26, 8, 44, 31, 22]

I'm trying to make a Lotto numbers generator but I can't make the code to generate 6 numbers that do not repeat.
As you can see in the Output 8 is repeating.

I'm not clear why in the If statement the code does not check if the random y variable is already in the z list.

Comment: Use `continue` instead of `break` to continue the loop from the top again.

Comment: `choices` returns *a list*. Checking whether a list exists in a list will (in your case) always be false.

Comment: Not capital" C". Try this y = random.choices(range(1,50))

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use [`random.sample`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/random.html#random.sample):

```
>>> from random import sample
>>> sample(range(1, 50), k=6)
[40, 36, 43, 15, 37, 25]
```

It already picks *`k`* unique items from the range.

Answer (score 5):

Check out this code, it works pretty well for me.

1. since choices returns a list, I used choice instead to return a number.
2. break stops the code so I used continue instead.
3. variable `I` can be omitted using `len(z)` in while statement. (as suggested by Mime)

.

```
import random
# I = 0
z = []
while len(z) < 6: # instead of I < 6: (Thanks to Mime)
    y = random.choice(range(1,50)) # edit: you can also use random.randint(1,49) instead of choice.
    if y in z:
        continue
    z.append(y) # instead of z += [y] (Thanks to deceze)
    # I += 1
print(z)
```

Comment: You could/should use `z.append` instead of `+=` a list…

Comment: You could also use `while len(z) < 6` and therefore omit the variable `I`

Answer (score 2):

`break` will, well, break out of the loop.

Use `continue` to continue the loop from the top again, and make sure you pick the first (and only) element returned from `random.Choices`:

```
while I < 6:
    y = random.choices(range(1,50))[0]
    if y in z:
        continue # skip to next iteration and continue
    z.append(y)
    I += 1
```

Or better, use `random.randint()` to pick the integer instead of expanding the full range every time:

```
while I < 6:
    y = random.randint(1,50)
    if y in z:
        continue # skip to next iteration and continue
    z.append(y)
    I += 1
```

Comment: That alone won't fix it. In fact, the `break` *would* prevent duplication, if the `if` condition worked…

Comment: @deceze Thanks, I just noticed. Answer updated

Comment: Now `choices` is a bad choice (pun intended) for the task at hand…

Comment: line `z+=y` gives you an error `int object is not iterable`. Also you misspelled `choices`

Answer (score 2):

You can also use walrus (`:=`) operator and check if `y` is not in `z`:

```
from random import randint
z = list()
while len(z) < 6:
    if (y := randint(1,50)) not in z: z += [y]
print(z)
```

Answer (score 1):

You should do multiple things:

1. use random.randint()
2. use .append() for arrays and not +=
3. use continue instead of break

Your code can look like this:

```
import random
I = 0
z = []
while I < 6:
    y = random.randint(1,50)
    if y in z:
        continue
    z.append(y)
    I += 1
print(z)
```